Debugging Nuxt 3.11+ in VS Code - missing code lines
I am using VS Code for Nuxt 3 development and my problem is that since Nuxt 3.11 the code lines are not displayed and linked to the code position in the "debug console" anymore and objects are shown as plain text.
This problem only concerns server side debugging.
What I did:
I am currently using Nuxt 3.14.1592 with Nitro 2.10.4 and Nuxi 3.15 as devDependency.
I found out that since Nuxt 3.11 debugging works differently as described here: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/debugging
Therefore I am using the launch.json "Example VS Code Debug Configuration" from that page in VS Code.
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "client: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "server: nuxt",
      "outputCapture": "std",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nuxi/bin/nuxi.mjs",
      "args": [
        "dev"
      ],
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "fullstack: nuxt",
      "configurations": [
        "server: nuxt",
        "client: chrome"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

(The only adjustment I made was removing the port 3000 from the original file "url": "http://localhost:3000" to fit my settings.)
I am using the VS Code "Start debugging (F5)" feature now (Green play button). (Until Nuxt 3.10 I was using "npm run dev" from the VS Code terminal, as PowerShell).
I am working on Windows 10 and using Node 22.11.0
This is what the Debug Console looks like in my case.
start of debug
console.log without code lines and plain text objects
Thanks for your ideas on this.
